# Matching HTML subtree with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to match something like this with beautifulsoup.

```
<a href="./SlimLineUSB3/SlimLine1BayUSB3.php">
<b>1 Bay SlimLine with both eSATA and USB 3.0</b>
</a>
```

In a regexp, it would look something like this. I want to capture the url.

```
<a href="\.(.*)">
<b>.*</b>
</a>
```

How do I go  about doing something like this with BeautifulSoup? I need to use the b tags inside of the 'a' tags I want, since that's the only thing that differentiates these 'a's from any other link on the page. It seems like I can only write regexps to match the tag name or specific attributes?

Comment: `I need to use the interior of the 'a' tag to match`. What should the element have within it for it to match? Do you want all links that contain just a single `<b>` element?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, that's much more clear than how I phrased it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the `href` from all `a` tags which contain one `b` tag:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """
... <html><head><title>Title</title></head><body>
... <a href="first/index.php"><b>first</b></a>
... <a><b>no-href</b></a>
... <div><a href="second/index.php"><b>second</b></a></div>
... <div><a href="third/index.php"><b>third</b></a></div>
... <a href="foo/index.php">no-bold-tag</a>
... <a href="foo/index.php"><b>text</b><p>other-stuff</p></a>
... </body></html>
... ... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> [a['href'] for a in soup('a', href=True) if a.b and len(a) == 1]
[u'first/index.php', u'second/index.php', u'third/index.php']
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done quite elegantly using an XPath expression if you don't mind using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de).

```
import lxml.html as lh

html = '''
<a href="./SlimLineUSB3/SlimLine1BayUSB3.php">
    <b>1 Bay SlimLine with both eSATA and USB 3.0</b>
</a>

<a href="./Some/URL.php"></a>

<a href="./Another/URL.php">
    <b>foo</b>
    <p>bar</p>
</a>
'''

tree = lh.fromstring(html)

for link in tree.xpath('a[count(b) = 1 and count(*) = 1]'):
    print lh.tostring(link)
```

**Result:**

```
<a href="./SlimLineUSB3/SlimLine1BayUSB3.php">
    <b>1 Bay SlimLine with both eSATA and USB 3.0</b>
</a>
```

Or if you wanted to use a method more similar to @ekhumoro's with lxml you could do:

```
[a for a in tree.xpath('a[@href]') if a.find('b') != None and len(a) == 1]
```